# Auto select when there is only one option in dropdown using ajax and liferay

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I've created one drop down box in that I have some options. If I have only one option it should select automatically.

Below is the dropdown box:

```
<select id="pubType" name="pubType" onchange="setUsageVars('_searchtabs_WAR_searchportlet_INSTANCE_1soVeAY6cpIy_', this)">
```

Comment: how you are adding `Option` to Drop Down ?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Liferay, Java or AJAX - I removed these tags. Otherwise you should explain furthermore what you exactly are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not posted code how you are adding elements to `Select`
I **assume** you are appending `Options` to `Select/Dropdown` like as bellow code :
Following code will help you to do this if your `data` having `length == 1`

```
for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
     if( data.length == 1 )
         $('#pubType').append($("<option>",{
                value:data[i].id,
                text:data[i].name,
                selected: "selected",
            }));
    else
        $('#pubType').append($("<option>",{
            value:data[i].id,
            text:data[i].name,
        }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through following example,
 how to auto select & disable a dropdownlist item if only one option is in dropdownlist, using Ajax Call.
I'm sure it 'll help you.

```
   success: function (response) {
       var $select = $('#ddlSchoolList');
       $select.empty();

      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          if (response.length == 1) {

               $('#ddlSchoolList').append($("<option>", {
                   value:response[i].InstanceId,
                   text: response[i].InstanceName,
                   selected: "selected",
                   disabled: "disabled",
               }));

           }
       else {
           $select.empty();
           $('<option>', {
               value: 0
           }).html("------Select------").appendTo($select);
           $.each(response, function (i, state) {
               $('<option>', {
                   value: state.InstanceId

               }).html(state.InstanceName).appendTo($select);
           });
        }
    }
```